# "Skip" value is giving error , return negetive value by default

Tags: node.js

I have got this error:

> MongoServerError: Skip value must be non-negative, but received: -9223372036854775808

router request:

```
router.post("/products/by/search", listBySearch);
```

`listBySearch` method in product controller:

```
exports.listBySearch = (req, res) => {
    let order = req.body.order ? req.body.order : "desc";
    let sortBy = req.body.sortBy ? req.body.sortBy : "_id";
    let limit = req.body.limit ? parseInt(req.body.limit) : 100;
    let skip = parseInt(req.body.skip);
    let findArgs = {};

    // console.log(order, sortBy, limit, skip, req.body.filters);
    // console.log("findArgs", findArgs);

    for (let key in req.body.filters) {
        if (req.body.filters[key].length > 0) {
            if (key === "price") {
                // gte - greater than price [0-10]
                // lte - less than
                findArgs[key] = {
                    $gte: req.body.filters[key][0],
                    $lte: req.body.filters[key][1]
                };
            } else {
                findArgs[key] = req.body.filters[key];
            }
        }
    }

    Product.find(findArgs)
        .select("-photo")
        .populate("category")
        .sort([
            [sortBy, order]
        ])
        .skip(skip)
        .limit(limit)
        .exec((err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "Products not found"
                });
            }
            res.json({
                size: data.length,
                data
            });
        });
};
```

Comment: So what's `req.body.skip`?

Comment: whetever you put in body of request , but here as per my request i did not put anything

Comment: If `req.body.skip` is empty, you're passing `NaN` as a value to `.skip()`, which is invalid.

Comment: ok , i need to passing value

Comment: `parseInt('')` returns `NaN`

Comment: i understand , i put .skip( 0 ) and its works

Comment: can i write -->let skip = req.body.skip?parseInt(req.body.skip):0;

Comment: I wouldn't advise using that construction, because it would still allow invalid values of `req.body.skip` to be passed to `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you state in your comments, the issue occurs when there's no value for `skip` passed in `req.body`, which means `skip = parseInt(undefined)`, which is `NaN`.

Instead, try setting a default skip value of 0:

```
let skip = parseInt(req.body.skip) || 0;
```